# Constructing ordinals which witness an iteration tree is continuously illfounded

Tags: set-theory

An iteration tree $\mathcal{T} = ( T, \langle M_n, E_n \mid n \in \omega\rangle)$ of length $\omega$ is *continuously illfounded* iff there are ordinals $\alpha_n$ for $n \in \omega$ such that 
$i_{nm}(\alpha_n) > \alpha_m$ whenever $nTm$.  (Here, $i_{nm} : M_n^{\mathcal{T}} \to M_m^{\mathcal{T}}$).

I am reading these [notes](http://www.math.cmu.edu/users/jcumming/Appalachian/steel_cmu_2015_files/Iteration-Ultrapowers.pdf) by John Steel and I am confused at some point in the proof that every "nice" iteration tree of length $\omega$ on $V$ has a well-founded cofinal branch.  If there is a nice iteration tree for which this fails, we construct ordinals which witness continuous illfoundedness, and I am having a problem here. I believe the point I'm stuck at should be quite obvious, but I can't convince myself of what is written.

**Note**: the "niceness" condition is on page 26 of the notes, definition 6.5, but I do not think it is necessary for the argument at hand. I can add it to the question if necessary.

The proof starts as follows:
Suppose not, and say $\mathcal{T} = ( T, \langle M_n, E_n \mid n \in \omega\rangle)$ is an iteration tree on $V$ which has no cofinal wellfounded branch.  Choose an ordinal $\eta$ such that
for every cofinal branch $b$, $i^{\mathcal{T}}_b(\eta)$ is in the illfounded part of $M^{\mathcal{T}}_b$ where $i^{\mathcal{T}}_b: M_0^{\mathcal{T}} = V \to M^{\mathcal{T}}_b$ is the direct limit map.

If there are no cofinal branches in $T$ we can cook up ordinals witnessing continuous illfoundedness by looking at the nodes rank in $T$.

So assume that $T$ does have cofinal branches.  For each cofinal branch $b$, and $n \in \omega$ we pick ordinals $\alpha^b_n$ with the property that $i_{nm}(\alpha^b_n) > \alpha^b_m$ whenever $nTm$ and $n,m \in b$.  Here, we require that $\alpha^b_n < i_{0n}(\eta)$ for all $b, n$.

If we do have such ordinals for a given branch $b$ then for each $n$, $i_{nb}(\alpha_n^b)$ is in the illfounded part of $M^{\mathcal{T}}_b$ (where $i_{nb} : M_n \to M^{\mathcal{T}}_b$ is the direct limit map).  Certainly there are ordinals $\alpha \in M_n^{\mathcal{T}}$ such that $i_{nb} (\alpha)$ is in the illfounded part of $M^{\mathcal{T}}_b$ but how do we know there are any below $i_{0n}(\eta)$?  Can it happen that $i_{0n}(\eta)$ is the least ordinal $\alpha \in M_n$ such that $i_{nb}(\alpha)$ is in the illfounded part?

Perhaps I am focusing too much on the limit model and the ordinals having to be in the illfounded part of it. At each finite stage, it seems ok to find an ordinal $\alpha_m^b \in M_m$ such that $\alpha_m^b< i_{nm}(\alpha_n^b)$ for all $nTm$. But it seems we need a lower bound so that the $\alpha_m^b$'s don't decrease to $0$. Can we find such $\alpha_m^b$ in $[\eta, i_{0m}(\eta))$ i.e. $\eta$ is the lower bound? Could we take $\alpha_m^b = \eta$ for every $m$.

After thinking about it more, I think my problem boils down to confusion on illfounded limit models. I don't seem to have much intuition on how they behave. Any explanation/insight would be much appreciated!

**Edit:** I realized I misread the notes and have modified the question to be more accurate.

---

Comment: Oh good. I'll delete my comment, you can delete yours.

Comment: I think you should be picking your $\eta$ large enough so that every $\alpha^b_n<\eta$, since if not how can we guarantee that $i^{\mathcal{T}}_b(\eta)$ will be in the illfounded part of the direct limit? In addition, you're looking at the functions associating $\alpha^b_n$'s to a  branch, so for this to be well-defined every $\alpha^b_n$ should be below $\eta$ for every continuously illfounded branch $b$. As an aside, Neeman's article in the handbook has the proof with more details (2.12)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! If you submit this as an answer I will accept it.  I think the ordering in the notes I linked to was a little misleading to me.  It looks like we first find the $\alpha^b_n$ and then fix $\eta$ whereas the reading of the notes is the other way around.